# Is there anyway to replicated regex term extraction with sphinx query?

Tags: sphinx

Using a simple regex:

```
Status: (.*?),(.*?)\s
```

I can easily extract "Updated" and "In-Progress" from

```
Status: In-Progress,Updated
```

see https://regex101.com/r/mV7gF5/1

I am trying to do something similar with Sphinx since it is much faster. Is there any way to do this with SphinxQL? I don't even mind if it requires post-processing but I can't for the life of me figure out a sphinxQL since it seems far more literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well sphinx could give you a list of documents containing the word 'Status' and even ones containing `Status: .*,.*` if was to add : and , to charset_table.

But it can't do any sort of term extraction, would need to post-process those documents (and probably execute the regular expression against them!). The closest would be to CALL SNIPPETS, which sort of does text matching, but it doesnt have a regex syntax.